# Nextjs sending GET instead of POST request

Tags: javascript, api, next.js

```
 const axios = (props) =>
  Axios({
    baseURL: 'https://example.com.ng/api',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      Authorization: `Token  ${API_KEY}`,
    },
    ...props,
  });


 const response = await axios({
        url: '/data',
        method: 'POST',
        data: {
          network: network_id,
          Ported_number: true,
          ...rest,
        },
      });
```

I'm sending this request to an external API but instead of creating new data for DB, I'm actually retrieving the already created data.
I don't know where I'm going wrong. Any kind of help will be highly appreciated.

PS: I tried making a POST request to MOCK API and it works as expected. when I contacted the owner of the API I'm trying to work with, they said, there are many clients using their API and none of the complaint has been reported.